# Grid overflowing DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml

Take a look at the image... notice how the grid that contains the text and the button overflows into the next column. Why is it doing that?

[image]

````
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Device" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Name" x:Name="DeviceColumn" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=DeviceColumn, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="Device" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <Button Name="FilterButton" Content="..." Width="30" Background="Transparent" Click="FilterColumn" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>```
````

Comment: It looks like there's a Margin of ~2 pixels to the left of the Grid. The Width looks like it matches.

Comment: How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you have a Style defined for Grid? When I try your XAML here it fits perfectly.

Comment: When you run it. Does clicking on that button overlap actually click the button? The designer is approximate.

Comment: Also. I would remove that binding to actual width from the grid. That could cause problems with any padding and margins.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I had a style in ```<Window.Resources>``` targeting type ```DataGridColumnHeader``` that had a Padding of 5,0,0,0.   Removing the padding solved the issue even though the issue was in the header of a ```DataGridTemplateColumn```  and not a ```DataGridColumnHeader```.  I guess a ```DataGridTemplateColumn```  is still a type of ```DataGridColumn``` and so a ```DataGridColumnHeader``` still applies.

Comment: @davecove great, glad you found it, Styles trickle down and can often cause unexpected results. I made an answer from my comment so you can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a Style defined that either affects the `Grid` (with a -2 Margin for example) or `DataGridColumnHeader`.